# Help Drools integration with Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, drools, drools-flow

I am new with Drools. I am integrating Drools with Scala. I am trying the project given at http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2010/12/using-jboss-rules-drools-in-scala.html. 
I have made a small change in the code to supply the Drools rule file as given below:

```
File f = new File("WeatherRules.drl"); 
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(f), ResourceType.DRL);
```

The code is running fine and there is no error but the rules are not working. The output I got is:

```
Creating Knowledge Session 
Creating and insertng Temperature 
Firing all rules
```

It seems that the configured rules are not working. The dependencies I am using in for is:

```
Scala: 2.9.0.1
Sbt: 0.7.7 
jaxb-xjc: 2.2.4-1 
drools-core: 5.2.0.Final 
drools-compiler: 5.2.0.Final 
jxl: 2.6 
xstream: 1.3.1
```

Am I missing something? Please help me to integrate Drools with scala. Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks, 
Puneet

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution to the problem. The solution is at:

http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools5-2-2-integration-with-scala2-9-0-1-td3229566.html

Puneet

Answer (score 1):

I think you should also include the Knowledge-API jar in your dependencies for execution, but it makes me wonder that the code didn't throw any exception so far...

good luck,
Ivano