# Drools rules with Scala,Akka

Tags: scala, akka, drools

I will have my first encounter with Drools rules engine in a Scala, Play environment. Are there any Drools -Scala ish libraries available? Eventually I would want to have Drools wrapped in an Akka Actor or something.

I have seen Hammurabi which isn't Drools but Drools like rules engine. Want to continue Drools path unless there are strong reasons against it. Any pointers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963710/help-drools-integration-with-scala

Comment: http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2010/12/using-jboss-rules-drools-in-scala.html